# Javascript validation is not working when i use struts 2 jquery submit button onClick event

Tags: javascript, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.1 . I am using submit button of it, i am calling javascript validation on onclick event but my form is submitting even though validation not done.Here is code:

```
<sj:submit
value="Add"
targets="idRightMainDiv"
button="true"
buttonIcon="ui-icon-gear"
formIds="addExerDetailsForm"
onclick="return SetsRepsFormValidate()"   //calling javascript validation 
tabindex="7"/>

function SetsRepsFormValidate() {
    var summary = "";
    summary += isSets();
    summary += isReps();

    if (summary != "") {
    dhtmlx.alert(summary);
    return false;
    }

    else {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution in this link this:

put this code in head section-

```
  <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $.subscribe('before', function(event,data) {
     var fData = event.originalEvent.formData;
     alert('About to submit: \n\n' + fData[0].value + ' to target '+event.originalEvent.options.target+' with timeout '+event.originalEvent.options.timeout );
    var form = event.originalEvent.form[0];
     if (form.echo.value.length < 2) {
      alert('Please enter a value with min 2 characters');
      // Cancel Submit comes with 1.8.0
      event.originalEvent.options.submit = false;
      }
   });
  $.subscribe('complete', function(event,data) {
     alert('status: ' + event.originalEvent.status + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + event.originalEvent.request.responseText + 
   '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
  });
  $.subscribe('errorState', function(event,data) {
    alert('status: ' + event.originalEvent.status + '\n\nrequest status: ' +event.originalEvent.request.status);
  });
 </script>
```

And wrote struts 2 jquery submit button's events-

```
            <div class="type-button">
                     <sj:submit  targets="result" 
                                    value="AJAX Submit" 
                                    timeout="2500" 
                                    indicator="indicator" 
                                    onBeforeTopics="before" 
                                    onCompleteTopics="complete" 
                                    onErrorTopics="errorState"  
                                    effect="highlight" 
                                    effectOptions="{ color : '#222222' }" 
                                    effectDuration="3000"/>
             </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really add validation to the `onsubmit` event of the form as the form can also be submitted by hitting the enter key.

Your current validation will only fire if the user clicks on the button.

Comment: But there is no onsubmit event in sj:submit button, i checked this [link](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag)

Comment: Yes I also used onsubmit event of the form but my validate function   is not calling

Comment: Are you sure it never gets called - can you put an alert statement in there to see if it triggers?

Comment: yes i also put alert box in called javascript fuction but it is not working with sj:submit button, previously i was working with s:submit button. please tell me what do i do?

Comment: There is a `validate` tag on the form and more information on client side validation here: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/client-side-validation.html

Comment: I think this is struts 2 client side validation framework, is it possible to do javascript  validation with sj:submit.

Comment: What does the resulting page look like?

Comment: it is returning included page in targets="idRightMainDiv" .